Statistical test to check if two samples come from the same DISCRETE distribution
I am computing hourly backward wind trajectories for the 1985-2023 period, and obtaining all the pixels that are crossed by these trajectories. I have the pixel ID frequencies for these trajectories - that is, I know how many times each pixel was crossed in this period. I can compute such trajectories considering up to 24 trajectories per day - but my interest is to reduce as much as possible the number of hourly trajectories per day. Hence, I want to know if the subset of pixel ID frequencies consisting of 3 hourly trajectories per day is the same as the frequency coming from the 24 trajectories per day (for every hour in the day).
To do that, I obtained the frequency for the pixel IDs considering both 24 and 3 trajectories per day. The CDFs and PDFs are both very similar:




Intuitively, at least looking at these pictures, I would definitely say that these samples come from the same distribution (note that the 3 trajectories per day sample is a subset from the 24 trajectories per day sample).
However, I wanted to be sure about this using a statistical test. It seemed to me that the most appropriate one would be the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I employed it on R using the following code:
> stats::ks.test(traj24$CellID, traj3$CellID)

Asymptotic two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
data:  traj24$CellID and traj3$CellID
D = 0.00082441, p-value = 0.002034
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

The CellID column consists on the ocurrence of each cell ID. For example, if cell ID 420 was crossed two times, then there are two observations for 420 in this column. The result of the test leads us to reject the null hypothesis that these two samples come from the same distribution. But this is very intrigating since, looking at the shape of the distributions, they look akwardly similar.
This rejection of the null also happens when I compare the 24 trajectories per day sample with a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 6 trajectories per day samples. The only case when this is not rejected is when I compare the 24 with the 12 trajectories per day, where the p-value is 0.84.
I am not sure if this is happening because the lower the ammount of trajectories per day, the smaller the sample size. And I am also not sure if I am using this test in the proper way. I would like to hear advices on how to properly run a statistical test that works for this discrete case including two different samples.
The data I am using is available in this link.

Welcome to CV, jparbache! See Schröer, G., & Trenkler, D. (1995). Exact and randomization distributions of Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests two or three samples. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 20, 185–202. The give an application of the test when ties are possible, which I believe will serve your interest for $\text{H}_{0}\text{: Samples drawn from same discrete distribution}$.

You are surprised that the test detects a difference, but this should not be surprising at all (even with the conservativeness that results from using the test for continuous distributions with discrete variables): the standard error of the difference in empirical cdfs under $H_0$ is proportional to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}$, so if the smaller of the two sample sizes is sufficiently large, the test will be able to detect tiny differences in distribution, smaller than would be visible to the eye. Eventually even to pick up differences that are smaller than 1 pixel in your plots...

Many posts on site discuss this issue (that large samples mean you pick up tiny, even trivial differences) across all manner of hypothesis tests. The same question (in the guise of various tests) comes up very regularly.
